# SQL Server: stored procedure return value for adding into table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I was wondering if there is a way to return the value 0 if adding into a table in a stored procedure goes wrong?

Something like this:

```
CREATE PROC Test 
@Var1 int, @Var2 VARCHAR(10) AS
     If ( INSERT INTO myTable (Integer, Character) VALUES (@Var1, @Var2) )
         Return 1
     Else
         Return 0
```

Is there a way to implement this idea that works in SQL Server?

Comment: What's the point? If it goes wrong it will throw an error so catch that. The error message and number will have more details of the specific issue than just  returning a `0`.

Comment: All I have gotten for now is to return 1 or 0. Nothing else. What im trying to do is to see if it works it returns the 1 otherwise it will be a 0. I can't find any similar examples like this on the internet and I'm still a beginner when it comes to use SQL Server.

Comment: So you get a 0. Then what? What can your "caller" do with it? Should it re-try, give up, return a 0 of its own, what? Martin has the right answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treating your question as academic, SQL Server supports TRY CATCH blocks:

```
CREATE PROC Test 
@Var1 int, @Var2 VARCHAR(10) AS
DECLARE @ret int;
BEGIN TRY
 INSERT INTO myTable (Integer, Character) VALUES (@Var1, @Var2) );
 SET @ret = 1
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
 SET @ret = 0;
END CATCH

RETURN @ret;
```

Answer (score 2):

If [`XACT_ABORT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is ON, and an error occurs on the `INSERT`, then your stored procedure as written will cause a SqlException to be sent to the client.  Your client can catch this exception and do something intelligent with it.

Also, if `XACT_ABORT` is ON, you can perform a SQL [`BEGIN TRY` / `END TRY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) to catch the error before exiting the stored procedure.  See Tab Alleman's answer for a way to do that.

Note that a generic error code of "something went wrong" makes it difficult to debug the actual problem in a production system.  You might be better letting SQL Server generate an exception.  Then your client can log that exception somewhere.  Alternatively, you could return 0 on success and a non-zero [`@@ERROR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188790.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) code on failure.

If `XACT_ABORT` is OFF, then it is possible (depending on the severity) that the query execution continues.  Then, you would need to handle the error somehow.  One possibility is like this:

```
CREATE PROC Test 
@Var1 int, @Var2 VARCHAR(10) AS
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT OFF
    INSERT INTO myTable (Integer, Character) VALUES (@Var1, @Var2)
    IF @@ERROR = 0
        RETURN 1 -- success
    ELSE
        RETURN 0 -- failure
END
```

Also, see this Microsoft TechNet article on [Returning Data by Using a Return Code](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190778(v=sql.105).aspx).  The [`RETURN` statement documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) might help.